# KQL timebased query rather than results

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql

So I've got a HTTP function that writes logs to app insights when its invoked.

I'm wanting to know when a period of time elapses when the HTTP function isn't called.

traces | where message contains "function invoked" | summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 10m)

This works, but it only pulls out the present of logs,

What I'm wanting is to know how many requests have hit this endpoint from now. Rather than it showing "no results". it should have a table showing the datetime and a value of 0.

that way I can show a flat line.

Answer (score 0):

[make-series](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-seriesoperator) operator

This works if you have at least one data point

```
traces 
| where message has "function invoked" 
| make-series count() on timestamp from ago(1h) to now() step 10m
| render timechart
```

If you might have no data points, you will need to use some tricks

```
union traces, (print timestamp = now(1ms))
| make-series countif(timestamp <= now()) on timestamp from ago(1h) step 10m
| render timechart
```